# Is possible to get notification by e-mail when a site or app pool is down (using IIS7)

Tags: iis-7, was

I am trying to find out if I can get notified when a site is down, or when a service running under WAS is no longer running.

I don't want to code a monitoring tool, I am sure there must be something out there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this

http://tools.pingdom.com/

Beside the cool online tools you have a subscription for monitoring your site.

I found a couple more, haven't used them. These seem totally free while pingdom tools is only free for one site.

http://www.uptimerobot.com

http://ezinedesigner.com

Comment: the last one seems to be dead link

Answer (score 0):

I also had this need, so I created an open source app called Pinger. You can do unlimited URLs with intervals of your choosing. The docs has instructions for getting running on Heroku quickly:

https://github.com/austinthecoder/pinger

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [Content Site Monitor](http://www.contentsitemonitor.com). It has a really simple and cool web interface that allows you to view your site’s up-time statistics on a desktop or mobile screen. It’s easy to configure your monitoring parameters as well.

It doesn't just ping your server to make sure that it's alive. It allows you to specify certain content/keywords that you want to monitor.  It will send you alert email if the content/keywords are missing from your site or if your site goes down.

Best of all, it’s free to monitor up to 3 sites!